# Use Pandas' apply() function on GeoDataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, geometry, apply, geopandas

I am trying to do a very simple thing. I have a geopandas geodataframe (*gdf*) with an attribute column (*gdf.att*) and a geometry column (*gdf.geometry*, all geometries are shapely points).

Now I want to create an extra column whose values are the result of a function of the point coordinates and the attribute. I'm trying to do this using apply() as below:

```
gdf['new_col'] = gdf.apply(lambda row : function([row.geometry.x, row.geometry.y], row.att))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'geometry'
```

It seems that within the apply function, *row* is a series of which I cannot call the geometry. But I don't understand this because if I run the test below to check what I get if I just return *row*, then I get a GeoDataFrame as output.

```
test = gdf.apply(lambda row: row) # after running this, test is the same as gdf
```

Does someone know how to use apply() with GDF's using multiple columns?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `print(type(gdf))`?

Comment: @Corralien <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>

Comment: Try to append `axis=1`: `gdf['new_col'] = gdf.apply(lambda row : function([row.geometry.x, row.geometry.y], row.att), axis=1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- created a MWE that matches your problem statement
- you have missed `axis=1` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html, hence you are applying to each column,  not each row.

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities')).rename(columns={"name":"att"})

def function(point, att):
    return att[int(point[0] % len(att))]

gdf['new_col'] = gdf.apply(lambda row : function([row.geometry.x, row.geometry.y], row.att), axis=1)

gdf.head(5)
```

|  | att | geometry | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Vatican City | POINT (12.453386544971766 41.903282179960115) | V |
| 1 | San Marino | POINT (12.441770157800141 43.936095834768004) | n |
| 2 | Vaduz | POINT (9.516669472907267 47.13372377429357) | z |
| 3 | Luxembourg | POINT (6.130002806227083 49.611660379121076) | o |
| 4 | Palikir | POINT (158.1499743237623 6.916643696007725) | k |